# Is there a built-in method for retrieving service availability from the MS Graph Bookings API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The Microsoft Bookings app provides a Booking Page that displays a series of available times slots for booking appointments. These times are based on several factors, depending on the settings applied by the Bookings app's administrator. These factors include: business hours, staff hours, previously booked appointments, the service's scheduling policy, and staff calendar availability (if staff have appointments set outside of the Bookings app in Outlook).

Is there a built-in method within the Microsoft Graph (Beta) Bookings API that returns a list of available time slots based on these factors? I cannot seem to locate this functionality in the beta documentation. I can find calls to show things like business hours and the scheduling policy of the services, but nothing that will aggregate these into available time slots, taking into account the availability of the staff from their Outlook calendars.

My logic is, if there is functionality for this in the Bookings app, it may be present in the API as well. I hope this isn't just wishful thinking.

Comment: An example from a different service's API is this one from the SetMore API: https://setmore.docs.apiary.io/#introduction/time-slots

Comment: If no docs then no such API. You can submit an feature request by [uservocie](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/)